# Should I throw ArgumentNullException and should I test it?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, null

Let's take an example of class with 3 dependencies and one method.

```cs
class Example
{
    private readonly IDependency1 _d1;
    private readonly IDependency2 _d2;
    private readonly IDependency3 _d3;

    public Example(IDependency1 d1, IDependency2 d2, IDependency3 d3)
    {
        _d1 = d1 ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(d1));
        _d2 = d2 ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(d2));
        _d3 = d3 ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(d3));
    }

    public string Method(string parameter)
    {
        if(parameter == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(parameter));

        return ...
    }
}
```

TDD suggests to test practically everything. So there should be 3 test that expects ArgumentNullException for each constructor dependency. Plus a test for the method when passed parameter is null. These tests doesn't look very beneficial to me and takes a non-zero amount of time. So my question is. Is it really worth it to test for ArgumentNullExceptions?

The other question is. When are these checks beneficial at all? Wouldn't it be better to have just documentation saying that passed method / constructor parameters must not be null? And isn't that obviously with regards to dependencies to constructor? And the other issue is: Assume I call methods like this in a *working tested* system. Wouldn't these checks unnecessarily slow things down (assuming that practically every method checks for null arguments)?

Comment: If you are doing TDD then you wrote that code to make the tests pass.You do not need to write more tests unless you want to change the behavior of the program.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it really worth it to test for ArgumentNullExceptions?

Sure, if you want to make sure they work properly.  That said, [Don't unit test trivial code.](https://blog.rendle.io/dont-unit-test-trivial-code/)

> When are these checks beneficial at all?

They insure the integrity of your system by preventing the creation of invalid objects.

> Wouldn't it be better to have just documentation saying that passed method / constructor parameters must not be null?

Why test the validity of anything, then?  You're saying to just document valid conditions, and hope that the user reads the documentation and does everything correctly?

> And isn't that obviously with regards to dependencies to constructor?

The purpose of throwing any exception in a constructor is to inform the caller that: **I cannot construct a valid object because you haven't provided me with what I need to do so.**

> Wouldn't these checks unnecessarily slow things down?

The cost is vanishingly small compared to the benefit.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed tedious and, arguably a waste of time, to write these trivial and not super useful tests by hand.  If you feel it necessary (check the article cited by @Robert Harvey first)

**Consider writing some code that will automatically test the null cases**.

For example, in Java, you can use reflection and send a single null argument to a list of methods of your class, such as your `Method()`.  For multi-argument methods and constructors it's a bit trickier but can he done by looping over the arguments, (perhaps with an option to ignore some)

Ignoring this null issue, you can **do the same for generic simple getters / setters with no validation**.  Set a random String, Integer, etc, get it back, and test for equality.